# Count The number of filled rows in column A, of Filtered data, that are blank in columns F through R

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I had been using,

```
=(COUNTIFS(A7:A31, "<>", F7:F31,"=",G7:G31,"=",H7:H31,"=",I7:I31,"=",J7:J31,"=",K7:K31,"=",L7:L31,"=",M7:M31,"=",N7:N31,"=",O7:O31,"=",P7:P31,"=",Q7:Q31,"=",R7:R31,"="))
```

But it isnt accurate when filters are applied.

I have been trying something along the lines of SUMPRODUCT or SUBTOTAL in collaboration with ISNUMBER and SEARCH but have had no luck.

Any help would be Greatly Appreciated.

Comment: what you have put here is so abstract. make it more self-explanatory by sharing screenshots and examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This formula should do what you want

`=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(A7,ROW(A7:A31)-ROW(A7),0)),0+(COUNTIF(OFFSET(F7:R7,ROW(A7:A31)-ROW(A7),0),"<>")=0))`

The `SUBTOTAL` part returns a 1 or 0 for each row, 1 only if the row is `visible` (not filtered) and populated. The `COUNTIF` part then returns a 1 only if the `F` to `R` columns in each row are all blank,so `SUMPRODUCT` effectively gives you a count of when both conditions are true, which is what you want